# Enter key fires an Event twice

Tags: events, extjs, event-handling

I am currently working on a project in which the end user has two ways of submitting data for analysis.
The first way is: he clicks on a button - the button's listener fires an event called "ProcessBtnClick"
The second way is: he/she presses ENTER - the ENTER key fires the "ProcessBtnClick" event

When the ENTER key is pressed, the "ProcessBtnClick" event gets fired twice, it seems like the click event gets fired this way as well. Is there any way of avoiding this behavior? If so, How?

I enabled the ENTER key as follows:

```
this.control({
           'container *' : {
               specialkey : this.onHandleSpecialKey
           }
          });
```

The onHandleSpecialKey is defined as follows:

```
onHandleSpecialKey: function(field, event, options) {
        if (event.getKey() == event.ENTER) {
            QuickCloseUI.app.fireEvent("ProcessBtnClick");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which event do you use? keyup? Please post example code.

Comment: In the edit I have included the code I use

Comment: Add a `console.log([field,event]);` at the beginning of `onHandleSpecialKey`. So you should be able to find out where the event comes from.

Comment: I think the problem is the query ` 'container *'`. If the textfield is inside a fieldcontainer where both are children of a container, both would call the onHandleSpecialKey function

Comment: Harry - Thanks that seems to be the issue. I appreciate it. PerryFlynn - I found the issue while debugging and using the console. Thanks a lot!